# Enable IPv6 on RHEL 8 via dhclient.conf modification

Tags: dhclient

How can I prepend IPv6 to RHEL 8 `dhclient.conf`?

This didn't work:

```
prepend dhcp6.name-servers 2606:4700:4700::1111, 2606:4700:4700::1001;
```

IPv4 has no issue but getting IPv6 to work is a problem.

Comment: There was a bug until 4.4.0 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/694135 indeed recommends the syntax you used. I wonder if this might be a regression. https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=643890#c10