# Why does /etc/resolv.conf keep changing?

Tags: resolv.conf

I am running a debian based linux vm using virt-manager with two ethernet interfacs one connected with NAT and the other is bridged to br0, in `/etc/network/interfaces` I have the following configuration

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

br0 has a dhcp server that in not connected to anything except for a switch

when I reboot the machine `/etc/resolv.conf` has the following entry

```
nameserver 192.168.150.1
```

which is the network address assigned by NAP, that being said when I try to `ping google.com` I get the error `temporary name resolution failure` then I add another entry which is

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

and the vm works fine and I can visit any website but after some time it check `/etc/resolv.conf` and it has one entry again, even if i left the machine running with out starting anny services or running any programs

Is there a way to find out what is overwriting `/etc/resolv.conf`
Is there a wat to add `nameserver 8.8.8.8` to `/etc/resolv.conf` if it is not found (without using bash files)

Comment: What is a NAP? My it be a NAT?

Comment: yeah NAT sorry for the mistake

Comment: Unless you have special DNS needs you can use a static /etc/resolv.conf. Many systems like systemd and NM use clever algorithms to cover all the possible cases but if you're the usual home desktop user, you can delete the link and roll your own file `nameserver 8..8.8.8' is all you need. I used to have DNS issues and now they're all gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it must. Yes, */etc/resolv.conf* should *keep changing* as long as some other service needs to update it.

And here lies the problem: which service? We need more information.

From the simple description in your question, there are only two interfaces, one is `lo`, which has no need to change `/etc/resolv.conf`, and the other is eth0, which is using the dhcp service. The dhcp service must renew its lease from the upstream router, switch, or, in your case, most probably, the virtual dhcp server from libvirt and inside the bridge.

I am assuming that the description of *two interfaces* is by looking at the configuration **inside** the VM, not the configuration of the guest.

One option, then, , may be to tell the dhcpclient to [override the servers given by the DHCP lease](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/593400) by adding to `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` inside your VM  this line:

```
supersede domain-name-servers 1.1.1.1, 2.2.2.2, 3.3.3.3;
```

Or by prepending, that is, [add as first DNS resolvers](https://coderwall.com/p/isgroq/setting-name-servers-via-dhclient), with the line:

```
prepend domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;
```

#### The Iceberg

The problem is way more complex than the above "tip of the iceberg" may indicate.

The virtual network configuration is complex. You must ensure that the bridge, which I assume is providing the 192.168.150.zz address (not the default xx.yy.122.zz) is correctly configured. Please read https://wiki.libvirt.org/page/VirtualNetworking

There are also many other alternative programs that could be updating the `/etc/resolv.conf` file. From your description it doesn't seem that, in this case, any of them is the problem. But so you know, there has been a very long competiton to take control of `/etc/resolv.conf` over the years, it is very present even today. Some programs that could want to take control of `/etc/resolv.conf` and change it from time to time are:

1. `resolvconf`. A program designed to take absolute control of `/etc/resolv.conf` and avoid any other program from changing it. Remove it.
2. `Network Manager` (which you don't report you are using). It has several entries to define a dns server to use. You might reset its configuration (by moving its configuration file), or [disable it](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_and_managing_networking/manually-configuring-the-etc-resolv-conf-file_configuring-and-managing-networking) and see if it solves the problem.
3. The file `/etc/network/interfaces` [might contain DNS configuration lines](https://kifarunix.com/make-permanent-dns-changes-on-resolv-conf-in-linux/), which doesn't seem to be the case here.
4. The `systemd` `resolved` service might be setting the local server 127.0.0.53, which you don't report [Related](https://askubuntu.com/a/1218720).
5. `dnsmasq` or similar DNS server migt be configured to take control of `resolv.conf`. Check if there is a `dnsmasq` program running.
6. The `dhclient` might be updating (as it should) `dhcp.conf` for each new lease. As explained above.

Answer (score 0):

Just spit balling here, I had an issue like that as well. The issue I was running into was Network manager was applying it's configuration over Resolv.conf, might want to check that out. I am currently writhing this bored at work, I will get more specifics if needed once I get home.

```
grep DNS /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-*
```

and see a DNS server in there and or

```
sudo vim /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

And add this to the [main] section:

```
dns=none
rc-manager=unmanaged
```

Comment: Yes it would be very helpful i f you could provide more specifics

Comment: if you check the Network manager configs

grep DNS /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-*

and see a DNS server in there and or 

sudo vim /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
And add this to the [main] section:

dns=none
rc-manager=unmanaged

Comment: could you explain what would this do exactly?

Comment: the first part would see if network manager has DNS configured. Network Manager will assume that it has the rights to configure the DNS if there's something configured. The second part will remove the DNS configuration from Network Manager

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is due to systemd (see the other answer), but it could be
any script a vendor might add, or systemd could be modified to require
other, more obscure commands to disable the "mangle the DNS" feature, so
I gave up at some point and set the file to be immutable, something like:

```
set -e
cd /etc
TMPFILE=`mktemp -q resolv.XXXXXXXXXX`
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" > "$TMPFILE"
chmod 0644 "$TMPFILE"
chattr -i resolv.conf
mv "$TMPFILE" resolv.conf
chattr +i resolv.conf
```

However, a vendor script could easily unset the immutable flag and then
mangle your DNS configuration; defense in depth would also include
trying to defang systemd. Also there is a slight race condition here.
Also, security policy frameworks such as SELinux (unless you've disabled
it) might complain about the inode change done above and require that
various rituals be observed (such as disabling it).